# Question about joinstate publisher and navigation?

Tags: navigation, joint-state-publisher, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,

i have a real robot and i'm trying to work with the navigation stack , i don't have an urdf model and i'm wondering if the navigation and the localization depend on it ? , and i want to know if i  have to use the JointState publisher and robotstate Publisher although i don't have a 3D model , is it esential to the navigation stack ?

thank you  for answering

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299455/question-about-joinstate-publisher-and-navigation-?/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Navigation only depends on having a TF frame for your robot and transforms for all the sensor data, but a full 3D model is not necessary.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-08-02**:
thnak you , because i have some trouble with le localization (i'm using hokuyo laser , imu ,encoder )  and i was wondering if it help when you have a 3d model